# After migration to .NET 8, a few Microsoft.Extensions dlls not getting found in bin folder

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-8.0

Migrated from .NET 6 to .NET 8.

After that migration, a few dlls are not present in `bin\Debug` folder.

For example, these DDLs were present in .NET 6, but not anymore in .NET 8, in my project's `bin\Debug` folder:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.FileSystemGlobbing.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll
System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.dll
System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll
```

**Note**: project and solution get built successfully with no errors.

I tried previous versions of nuget packages, but I still have the same issue.

While running application or powershell modules I am getting errors "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: If the build is successful - then why are you asking / inquiring about this??  .....

Comment: does it work (as in it runs and does what it supposed to do?) else why ask this question?

Comment: While running application or powershell modules I am getting errors  "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Http, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: Can you please post a [mre] somewhere like github?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of .NET Core 3.0, many ASP.NET Core assemblies are no longer published to NuGet as packages. Instead, the assemblies are included in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` shared framework,it's more recommaned to use shared framework now

And  the projects that target the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK implicitly reference the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework,you could just remove the reference to the packages

For projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` or `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor` SDK ,you could remove the packages and add framework reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For example, the dll in your error message would be in this location when you work with shared framework:

[image]

Documents related:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/metapackage-app?view=aspnetcore-8.0